# Python griddata meshgrid

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mesh, interpolation

in Python I want to interpolate some data using scipy.interpolate.griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi).

Since I want my unequal spaced original data on the X-Y grid map on an equal spaced XI-YI grid I have to use a meshgrid as:

```
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid([1,2,3], [2,5,6,8])
XI,YI = numpy.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5,6,7])
print scipy.interpolate.griddata(X,Y,X**2+Y**2,XI,YI)
```

Unfortunately it seems as scipys' griddata does not accept matrices as input for x,y,z in contrast to matlab's griddata-function. Does anyone has a hint for me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The correct call sequence in your case is

```
print scipy.interpolate.griddata((X.ravel(),Y.ravel()), (X**2+Y**2).ravel(), (XI, YI))
```

I.e., you need to cast the input data points to 1-d. (This could be fixed to work without the `.ravel()`s in the next version of Scipy.)

Comment: @pv: Thx, it works! Why do you merge the matrices X,Y and XI,YI to a new array via (X,Y) and (XI,YI), respectively? Because griddata expects five variables. But by doing so only three variables remain?!

Comment: No, griddata does not expect five variables, only three: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reshape your grids, griddata expects a list of points with coordinates in column form:

```
points = transpose(reshape((X,Y), (2,12)))
pointsI = transpose(reshape((XI,YI), (2,12)))
Z = reshape(X**2+Y**2, 12)

print scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, Z, pointsI)
```